# Parsing the cfg file froom YOLO-Darknet in OpenCV DNN

Tags: c++, opencv, darknet

I have followed this link to train yolo with my own dataset. I'm not using the CIAFR10 data.
https://pjreddie.com/darknet/train-cifar/

This is the cfg file named as cifar.cfg

```
[net]
batch=128
subdivisions=1
height=28
width=28
channels=3
max_crop=32
min_crop=32

hue=.1
saturation=.75
exposure=.75

learning_rate=0.001
policy=poly
power=4
max_batches =1000
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
filters=4
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[avgpool]

[softmax]
groups=1

[cost]
type=sse
```

It classifies the test images on Ubuntu 16.04 properly. 
I have used this cgf file and corresponding wights in the OpenCV3.4 DNN module. I'm using the Visual studio 2017.

```
 String modelFile = "cifar_small.cfg";
 String modelBinary = "cifar_small.weights";
```

When the line below is executed, I get the error message:

```
dnn::Net net = readNetFromDarknet(modelFile,modelBinary);
```

Error message:
OpenCV Error: Parsing error (Unknown layer type: avgpool) in `cv::dnn::darknet::ReadDarknetFromCfgFile, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_io.cpp, line 503

Also, for the sooftmax and see. Looks like DNN is not able to comprehend these terms.
Can someone let me know how to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remove the avgpool then the classification result by net.forward() is unreadable. It is the form of 1 channel with rows and columns equal to 0. When I passed the other model from tensorflow( .pb) I get 4 probabilities for each class.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the same cfg file? Try converting the line endings to your OS-specific one.

The avgpool section seems empty. What happens if you simply remove it?

Comment: I get a classification result which is a one channel matrix which number of columns and rows equal to -1. I can see that it holds a data, but not able to access it or use it. Can someone help how to use this classification result which is cv::Mat? Thanks